# Multiple item template inside grid view in Windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

In a gridview item template , is it possible to have multiple templates ? In my screen i am having set of icons in a single section of GridView control. I wqant to have one of the icon to have a larger dimension. How can i achive it.

```
<GridView>
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Grid/>
<DataTemplate/>
<GridView.ItemTemplate/>
<GridView/>
```

In this template the dimension igive for the grid will remain same for all the elements. How can i customize it so that onne of the item have a grid of different dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need a [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx). You can select an appropriate template for the selected object in the grid/list.

Sample for selector:

```
class TemplateSelectorMyPage : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate NormalIconTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate BigIconTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore( object item, DependencyObject container )
        {
            var uiElement = container as UIElement;
            if( uiElement == null )
            {
                return base.SelectTemplateCore( item, container );
            }

            if ( item is BigIconItem )
            {
                return BigIconTemplate;
            }
            else if ( item is NormalIconItem )
            {
                return NormalIconTemplate;
            }
            return base.SelectTemplateCore( item, container );
        }
```

In the XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:TemplateSelectorMyPage  x:Key="mySelector"
        BigIconTemplate="{StaticResource myBigIconTemplate}"
        NormalIconTemplate="{StaticResource myNormalIconTemplate}">
    </local:TemplateSelectorBusinessPage>
</Page.Resources>
```

In the Grid XAML:

```
<GridView           
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource mySelector}"
```

Comment: Thanks. How can i set the template while databinding the gridview control?

Comment: in TemplateSelectorMyPage after `if ( item is BigIconItem )` you are free to change the behavior as you want to select appropriate template. Templates is kept in `DataTemplate` properties.